# Magento 2 how to use depends in menu for system configuration dependency

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

In magento1.x if we want to display menu depends on system configuration of our module then we use following code for ex.

```
<menu>
    <test translate="title">
       <depends>
           <config>section/group/field</config>
       </depends>
       <title>Test Menu</title>
    </test>
</menu>
```

How can we achieve this in magento 2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this syntax, If you want to add `menu` based on `system configuration`. You can change your value according your configuration with the `catalog/Some_value/enabled`

```
dependsOnConfig="catalog/Some_value/enabled"
```

If you want to check more menu you can easily find options from below path or visit below this [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd#L52)

`magento\vendor\magento\module-backend\etc\menu.xsd`